# Issue writing data to csv file in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue writing to a CSV file in ruby and can't figure out.

```
> header = "Full Name, Email, Phone Number" csv_file =
> CSV.open("myfile.csv", "wb") do |csv|
>     csv << header
>     inactive_users_id.each do |inactive_id|  #inactive_users_id is just an array on integers, which represent user id
>         full_name = User.find(inactive_id).full_name
>         email = User.find(inactive_id).email
>         phone_num = User.find(inactive_id).phone_number
>         desired_info = Array.new
>         desired_info.push(full_name)
>         desired_info.push(email)
>         desired_info.push(phone_num)
>         csv << desired_info
>       end 
>    end
```

I do get following errors:

1. undefined method `map' for "Full Name, Email, Phone
   Number":String
2. if I remove line csv << header my csv file is
       literally like this: [138] --> which represents the id and other
       things are not there.

What could be the issue?
Thank you!

Comment: `header = ["Full Name", "Email", "Phone Number"]`. `CSV` expects an `Array` of columns. It will handle the commas.

Comment: I changed the header, but it not even written to the csv file. The main issue is why the array desired_info is not written to the csv file.

Comment: See also How to write columns header to a csv file with Ruby?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905985/how-to-write-columns-header-to-a-csv-file-with-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot replicate your issues please try this instead:

```
headers = ["Full Name", "Email", "Phone Number"]
CSV.open("myfile.csv", "wb", write_headers: true, headers: headers ) do |csv|
  User.where(id: inactive_users_id)
      .pluck(:full_name, :email, :phone_number)
      .each do |row|
        csv << row
      end
end
```

Here we are collecting all the `User`s in 1 query (rather than your current 3 per `User`) and just the needed columns are converted to an `Array` (using `#pluck`). Then we just push each one into the `csv` as a row

As pointed out in the comments in rails 3 `pluck` will not work with multiple columns (or at all depending on version) instead one should use `select` and then reference the attributes inside the loop to to create the row

Comment: Since there's a tag of ROR-3 on this question `pluck` won't work. Use `select` instead :)